# How to do that when the mouse pointer hovor QListWidgetItem, then the QListWidgetItem emit a signal?

Tags: qt

Recently, I want that QListWidgetItem can emit a signal, when the mouse pointer enter. Show a QStackedWidget, when leave, hide the QStackedWidget;
I defined a class My_ListWidget; in the class i override enterEvent and leaveEvent. But this is i hover the QListWidget not the QListWidgetItem, and it always show the first of the QStackedWidget.

Comment: `QListWidgetItem` is not a widget so that you cannot handle mouse actions on it directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

override `mouseMoveEvent` and grab the `QListWidgetItem` under the cursor with `itemAt(event.pos())`

edit: instead of overriding mouseEvent you can use the signal `entered` which will also pass the ModelIndex of the item end then use leaveEvent to clear the stacked widget, you need to activate mouseTracking for this to work

Comment: Can you give an example, i'm a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had some problems with getting the Item via `itemAt`. When subclassing QListWidget, you can enable mouse tracking with setMouseTracking(True) and use `itemEntered` and `leaveEvent`

```
class My_ListWidgetClass(QListWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QListWidget.__init__(self)

        self.setMouseTracking(True)

class Main(...):
    def __init__(self):

        self.centralWidget.connect( self.My_ListWidgetInstance,
                                    SIGNAL('itemEntered(QListWidgetItem *)'),
                                    self.whenItemEntered_doThis)

        self.centralWidget.connect( self.My_ListWidgetInstance,
                                    SIGNAL('leaveEvent(QEvent *)'),
                                    self.whenItemLeft_doThis)

    def whenItemEntered_doThis(self, QLWItem):
        # you can apply behavior here according 
        # to the QListWidgetItem given as argument 
        # e. g. get itemtext (itemtext = str(QLWItem.text())

    def whenItemLeft_doThis(self, Event):
        # executed when an item was left
        # unfortunatelly I can't explain, what you
        # can do with the event. I didn't need it...
```